# The system failed to register pointer (PTR)

Tags: dns

I got this issue on my Windows 10 client which is part of 'mydomain.com'.

- I get it when the PC boots
- I get it when I do this: ipconfig /registerdns
- nslookup -querytype=ns mydomain.com seems to show valid information (from the PC)
- nslookup -q=soa mydomain.com seems to show valid information (from the PC)
- I have a Reverse Lookup Zone called 5.168.192.in-addr.arpa (No entry for the PC exists)
- I have 2 Domain Controllers which host the DNS aswell (192.168.5.10, 192.168.5.11)
- Reverse Lookup Zone > Dynamic Updates are set to 'Nonsecure and secure' / 'secure' (no difference)
- dcdiag /test:DNS /s:dc1.mydomain.com passed on all but RREG (complains about missing SRV which I can verify are there)
- I have an external DHCP, Microtik (not sure if that matters at all)

```
The system failed to register pointer (PTR) resource records (RRs) for network adapter
with settings:

           Adapter Name : {7CF4C64F-39D8-4241-A44F-EDCDC5175E35}
           Host Name : ClientPC
           Adapter-specific Domain Suffix : mydomain.com
           DNS server list :
                192.168.5.10, 192.168.5.11
           Sent update to server : <?>
           IP Address :
             fdd3:ab80:b35:4d37:9940:cd20:7a87:c672

The cause was DNS server failure. This may be because the reverse lookup zone is busy or missing on the DNS server that your computer needs to update. In most cases, this is a minor problem because it does not affect normal (forward) name resolution.

If reverse (address-to-name) resolution is required for your computer, you can manually retry DNS registration of the network adapter and its settings by typing 'ipconfig /registerdns' at the command prompt. If problems still persist, contact your DNS server or network systems administrator. See event details for specific error code information.
```

Comment: What server hosts the reverse lookup zone? Is it configured to allow unauthenticated updates (or updates in general)? Does its log show the update requests being received?

Comment: I have 2 Domain Controllers which host the DNS aswell (192.168.5.10, 192.168.5.11). I do not know about the permission to update (what should I google for this). Where would I look for the log ?

Comment: Check the DNS zone settings first regarding their dynamic-update mode; I don't know about MS DNS server's logging so I'd first start with a general packet capture (Wireshark) to make sure the packets are at least going the right way.

Comment: Reverse Lookup Zone > Dynamic Updates are set to 'Nonsecure and secure'
There is an Event Viewer on the DC but that does not show any errors. So the packets might not arrive

Comment: That's when you fire up Wireshark – on the client first, see what it shows when you do `ipconfig /renew`, whether it looks up the correct SOA and talks to the correct server. Keep in mind that when it's updating the reverse zone, it also needs to look up **SOA of the reverse zone,** not of the forward.

Comment: The SOA seems okay (but I am getting to my DNS limits here)
I haven't gotten to the wireshark yet but I tried  dcdiag /test:DNS /s:dc1.mydomain.com and that passed on all but RREG (complains about missing SRV which I can verify are there)